# how to make a simple watch in wx python

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Could someone tell me please, how to make a simple wxpython

```
  import wx
    import time

    class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
        """ We simply derive a new class of Frame. """
        def __init__(self, parent, title):
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(200,100))
            self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
            self.Show(True)

    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame(None, 'Small editor')

app.MainLoop()
```

I'm wondering how may I take datetime at the moment and show it in a frame

Comment: Figure out what you want to display in your Frame. Could be numbers like a digital clock, or graphics like the face of a dial clock. Next, determine how to display or draw those things. This will determine what format you need get the date and/or time into from datatime, which will be your final task.

Comment: I meant digital cloack and without drawing just like numbers

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to display the datetime within/inside the GUI (as numbers, not in clock format), you can use the wx.DateTime.Now() function. Read more details in the wxPython doc [here](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/DateTime.html#DateTime.Now). You can input the following:

```
now = wx.DateTime.Now()
timecheckText = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Sample sentence here:\t%s\n"%(now.Format("%c", wx.DateTime.PST)), (3,30))
```

What this does is it inputs the datetime within a wx.StaticText function and prints the current day, month, year, time and timezone once initiated. Also, no need to 'import datetime', just 'import wx'.

Answer (score 2):

> *"I'm wondering how may I take datetime at the moment and show it in a frame"*

use the `time` module to get the system time:

```
import time
time.strftime('%d %m %Y')
```

As example how to access this module. Now in the Python interpreter, try `help(time)` and read up on the different timezone commands, and formatting commands, to get the value you need.

Comment: yes, I've known it already, I interest how it use in GUI, I was manage to make it in Tk module, but here I misunderstood a bit

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at the wxPython demo. There are a couple widgets that you should check out. One is the AnalogClock. It's really neat. Then there's the LEDNumberCtrl. There's a demo of that where it shows the current time updating in real time.

If you need to show a date, then try the DatePickerCtrl

UPDATE: Here's a code example:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

        dpc = wx.DatePickerCtrl(self, size=(120,-1),
                                style = wx.DP_DROPDOWN
                                      | wx.DP_SHOWCENTURY
                                      | wx.DP_ALLOWNONE )
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_DATE_CHANGED, self.OnDateChanged, dpc)
        sizer.Add(dpc, 0, wx.ALL, 50)

        # In some cases the widget used above will be a native date
        # picker, so show the generic one too.            
        dpc = wx.GenericDatePickerCtrl(self, size=(120,-1),
                                       style = wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL
                                       | wx.DP_DROPDOWN
                                       | wx.DP_SHOWCENTURY
                                       | wx.DP_ALLOWNONE )
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_DATE_CHANGED, self.OnDateChanged, dpc)
        sizer.Add(dpc, 0, wx.LEFT, 50)


    def OnDateChanged(self, evt):
        print "OnDateChanged: %s\n" % evt.GetDate()

########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, title="DatePickers")
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: >If you need to show a date, then try the DatePickerCtrl. could you give a simple sample? please?

Comment: Did you even look at the demo? I just copied the code from there

Comment: Then you should look at the LEDNumberCtrl that I mentioned